# Stripe - Split payment between multiple destination

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to split a payment between me (platform), beneficiary 1 and beneficiary 2 using Stripe Connect (Standard)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently supported in Stripe. You may manually split the payment up in your code and receive from each end the split amount of the payment.

Reference [Split funds from a single charge between different sellers using Connect](https://support.stripe.com/questions/split-funds-from-a-single-charge-between-different-sellers-using-connect)

Comment: Hmm, the support article does say that, but I would have said that you can do this by using 'Separate Charges and Transfers' : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers. It's one of the documented use cases on https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#types "Multiple users are involved in the transaction". Seems like a mistake.

Comment: It states that's recommended for Express and Custom accounts. Do you think it's also possible with Standard accounts?

Comment: It's possible(the API won't stop you) but not recommended. For example, all the liability for refunds/chargebacks is on you as the platform and you have limited control over Standard accounts to try to recoup funds. You should only use Standard accounts with Direct, for that use case you should try to use Express.